# Validating date/datetime object data in a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have a log file which will have one date time. But to avoid any issues, I would like to validate the date time or just the date from date time object when I read the file.

So if my file has `"Mon, 13 Apr 2015 12:43:23 -0500"` as data in it, I tried doing `DateTime.parse(filef.readline())` or `Date.parse(filef.readline())` to get the date object and then checking it. This returns the date while the data in file is a date. However if the data in file is some junked text like `"this is a junk text for testing"`, my solution returns me `"Mon, 1 Jun 2015 00:00:00 -5000"` and my check for datetime/date becomes valid.

What is the best way to check the data in the file is a valid date/datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime.rfc2822` method to load from that string format like:

```
dateTime = DateTime.rfc2822('Sat, 3 Feb 2001 04:05:06 +0700') rescue nil
```

If `dateTime` is `nil`, then the string was invalid.

More information:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-rfc2822